# MediaElement control on WinRT behaves differently between ARM and x86/x64 processor

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, mediaelement

I am working on a Windows Store application that utilize MediaElement control in WinRT (C# language).  Everything worked as expected until I start dealing with the PlaybackRate property .  I tested my application on Windows Surface RT (ARM based), Eee Slate (x64 based device) and desktop PC running windows 8 (x64 based), and found that while both the x64 devices honor the changes I made on the PlaybackRate propety, the property PlaybackRate (and DefaultPlaybackRate) was totally ignored on Surface RT.

At first I thought I made some coding mistake, so I used the official Windows Store Samples (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Media-Playback-003619be), and the exactly same experience.

So does PlaybackRate (and DefaultPlaybackRate) not supported in ARM based devices?  Any workaround?

Comment: I wonder if it's due to buffering? It may be that the playback rate doesn't work if the video is not buffered enough.

Create a control to display changes in MediaElement.BufferingProgress, maybe wait until the video is fully buffered (or until it's buffered to a certain point) before attempting to change the playback rate.

Also, maybe try updating your codecs/video drivers. It may be that the current drivers you have are simply not responding.

I do know that most apps tend do just do skipping (+30s/-10s/etc) as opposed to FF/RW.

Answer (score 0):

You  can try to remove the attributes [AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AudioDeviceType="Multimedia”] from the XAML of the MediaElement, somebody has tried it and the PlaybackRate responds correctly on both ARM and INTEL machines.